# Want to remove elements based on first character - Python

Tags: python, startswith

This is a program that lists all the substrings except the one that starts with vowel letters.

However, I don't understand why startswith() function doesn't work as I expected. It is not removing the substrings that start with the letter 'A'.

Here is my code:

```
ban = 'BANANA'

cur_pos=0
sub = []

#Finding the substrings
for i in range(len(ban)):
    limit=1
    for j in range(len(ban)):
        a = ban[cur_pos:limit]
        sub.append(a)
        limit+=1
    cur_pos+=1 
 

#removing the substrings that starts with vowels
for i in sub:
    if (i.startswith(('A','E','I','O','U'))):
        sub.remove(i)

print(sub)
```

Comment: What means *doesn't work as I expected* What is your expactation and what is what you get?

Comment: It is not removing the substrings that start with the letter 'A'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Why this doesn't work...

To answer your question, the mantra for this issue is **delete array elements in reverse order**, which I occasionally forget and wonder whatever has gone wrong.

### Explanation

The **problem** isn't with `startswith()` but using `remove()` inside this specific type of *for loop*, which uses an *iterator* rather than a *range*.

```py
for i in sub:
```

This **fails** in this code for the following reason.

```py
ban = 'BANANA'

cur_pos=0
sub = []

#Finding the substrings
for i in range(len(ban)):
    limit=1
    for j in range(len(ban)):
        a = ban[cur_pos:limit]
        sub.append(a)
        limit+=1
    cur_pos+=1 

print(sub)

#removing the subtrings that start with vowels
for i in sub:
    if (i.startswith(('A','E','I','O','U'))):
        sub.remove(i)
    print(sub)
print(sub)
```

I've added some print statements to assist debugging.

Initially the array is:

```
['B', 'BA', 'BAN', 'BANA', 'BANAN', 'BANANA', '', 'A', 'AN', 'ANA', 'ANAN', 'ANANA', '', '', 'N', 'NA', 'NAN', 'NANA', '', '', '', 'A', 'AN', 'ANA', '', '', '', '', 'N', 'NA', '', '', '', '', '', 'A']
```

...then we eventually get to remove the first `'A'`, which seems to be removed fine...

```
['B', 'BA', 'BAN', 'BANA', 'BANAN', 'BANANA', '', 'AN', 'ANA', 'ANAN', ...etc...
```

...but there is some nastiness happening behind the scenes that shows up when we reach the next vowel...

```
['B', 'BA', 'BAN', 'BANA', 'BANAN', 'BANANA', '', 'AN', 'ANAN',
```

Notice that `'ANA'` was removed, not the expected `'AN'`!

**Why**?

Because the `remove()` modified the array and shifted all the elements along by one position, but the `for` loop index behind the scenes does not know about this. The index is still pointing to the next element which it expects is `'AN'` but because we moved all the elements by one position it is actually pointing to the `'ANA'` element.

### Fixing the problem

One way is to append vowel matches to a new empty array:

```py
ban = 'BANANA'

cur_pos=0
sub = []
add = []

#Finding the subtrings
for i in range(len(ban)):
    limit=1
    for j in range(len(ban)):
        a = ban[cur_pos:limit]
        sub.append(a)
        limit+=1
    cur_pos+=1 

#adding the subtrings that don't start with vowels
for i in sub:
    if (not i.startswith(('A','E','I','O','U'))):
        add.append(i)
print(add)
```

### Another way

There is, however a simple way to modifying the original array, as you wanted, and that's to iterate through the array in reverse order using an index-based `for` loop.

The important part here is that you are **not modifying** any of the array elements that you are processing, only the parts that you are finished with, so that when you remove an element from the array, the array index won't point to the wrong element. This is common and acceptable practice, so long as you understand and make clear what you're doing.

```py
ban = 'BANANA'

cur_pos=0
sub = []

#Finding the subtrings
for i in range(len(ban)):
    limit=1
    for j in range(len(ban)):
        a = ban[cur_pos:limit]
        sub.append(a)
        limit+=1
    cur_pos+=1 

#removing the badtrings that start with vowels, in reverse index order
start = len(sub)-1  # last element index, less one (zero-based array indexing)
stopAt = -1 # first element index, less one (zero-based array indexing)
step = -1 # step backwards
for index in range(start,stopAt,step):  # count backwards from last element to the first
    i = sub[index]
    if (i.startswith(('A','E','I','O','U'))):
        print('#'+str(index)+' = '+i)
        del sub[index]
print(sub)
```

For more details, see the official page on `for`
https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#index-6

Aside: This is my favourite array problem.

Edit: I just got bitten by this in Javascript, while removing DOM nodes.

Answer (score 1):

It is not a good practice to iterate a list then removing item during the loop. I suggest you change it to this:

```
sub2=list()
#removing the substrings that starts with vowels
for i in sub:
    if not (i.startswith(('A','E','I','O','U'))):
        sub2.append(i) 
print(sub2)
```

So if the substring do not starts with vowel, then add it to another list sub2.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments in python you shouldn't remove items from a list while iterating its elements since you mutate the original list before the loop ends. If you want to do that you'll either have to use a another list and then assign it to your old one or do it directly using a list comprehension like so:

```py
sub = [i for i in sub if not i.startswith(('A','E','I','O','U'))]
```